# Shortest path in dag saga: Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, pathfinding

I have this Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm:

**net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.AbstractWeightedPathFinder**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import net.coderodde.graph.AbstractGraphNode;

/**
 * This abstract class defines the API and utilities for path finder algorithms.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <N> the actual graph node implementation type.
 */
public abstract class AbstractWeightedPathFinder<N extends AbstractGraphNode<N>> {

    /**
     * Searches a shortest path from {@code source} to {@code target}
     * 
     * @param source
     * @param target
     * @return a shortest path, or an empty list if target not reachable.
     */
    public abstract List<N> find(N source, N target);

    /**
     * Traces back the path found by a path finder.
     * 
     * @param target    the target node.
     * @param parentMap the map mapping each node to its parent node.
     * @return a path as a list of nodes.
     */
    protected List<N> tracebackPath(N target, Map<N, N> parentMap) {
        List<N> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        N current = target;

        while (current != null) {
            // Append 'current' to the list.
            ret.add(current);
            current = parentMap.get(current);
        }

        // Here, the path in wrong order, reverse.
        Collections.<N>reverse(ret);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

**net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support.DijkstraPathFinder**:

```
package net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.support;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import net.coderodde.graph.AbstractGraphNode;
import net.coderodde.graph.AbstractWeightFunction;
import net.coderodde.graph.pathfinding.AbstractWeightedPathFinder;

/**
 * This class implements Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6
 * @param <N> the actual graph node implementation type.
 */
public class DijkstraPathFinder<N extends AbstractGraphNode<N>> 
extends AbstractWeightedPathFinder<N> {

    /**
     * The weight function.
     */
    private final AbstractWeightFunction<N> weightFunction;

    /**
     * Constructs this shortest path finder with given weight function.
     * 
     * @param weightFunction the weight function.
     */
    public DijkstraPathFinder(AbstractWeightFunction<N> weightFunction) {
        this.weightFunction = 
                Objects.requireNonNull(weightFunction,
                                       "The weight function is null.");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc }
     */
    @Override
    public List<N> find(N source, N target) {
        checkNodes(source, target);

        Queue<NodeWrapper<N>> open = new PriorityQueue<>();
        Set<N> closed = new HashSet<>();

        Map<N, N> parentMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map<N, Double> distanceMap = new HashMap<>();

        open.add(new NodeWrapper<>(source, 0.0));
        parentMap.put(source, null);
        distanceMap.put(source, 0.0);

        while (!open.isEmpty()) {
            N current = open.poll().node;

            if (current.equals(target)) {
                return tracebackPath(target, parentMap);
            }

            // 'current' is settled.
            closed.add(current);

            for (N child : current.children()) {
                if (!closed.contains(child)) {
                    double w = distanceMap.get(current) + 
                               weightFunction.get(current, child);

                    if (!distanceMap.containsKey(child) 
                            || distanceMap.get(child) > w) {
                        open.add(new NodeWrapper<>(child, w));
                        distanceMap.put(child, w);
                        parentMap.put(child, current);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return Collections.<N>emptyList();
    }

    // An ad hoc structure for describing nodes and costs.
    private static final class NodeWrapper<N> 
    implements Comparable<NodeWrapper<N>> {

        N node;
        double g;

        NodeWrapper(N node, double g) {
            this.node = node;
            this.g = g;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(NodeWrapper<N> o) {
            return Double.compare(g, o.g);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checks the source and target nodes are in order.
     * 
     * @param <N> the actual graph node implementation type.
     * @param source the source node.
     * @param target the target node.
     */
    private static <N extends AbstractGraphNode<N>> 
        void checkNodes(N source, N target) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(source, "The source node is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(target, "The target node is null.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(source.getOwnerGraph(), 
                               "The source node does not belong to any graph.");
        Objects.requireNonNull(target.getOwnerGraph(),
                               "The target node does not belong to any graph.");

        if (source.getOwnerGraph() != target.getOwnerGraph()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "The source and the target node do not belong to the " +
                    "same graph");
        }
    }
}
```

Please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: ["How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions"](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/how-to-get-the-best-value-out-of-code-review-asking-questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Should check for duplicate node

Since your algorithm adds duplicate node entries to the priority queue as opposed to the "decrease key" method, you should check to see whether you have already handled a node.  Otherwise you will waste time iterating through its children for no reason.

You could just add a simple check:

```
        // Add this check
        if (closed.contains(current)) {
            continue;
        }

        // 'current' is settled.
        closed.add(current);
```